# java unable to find the error to print a prime number

Tags: java

This program gets 4 input from the user and prints out all the pairs except for the duplicate pairs. I wanted it print only the pairs that sum equals a prime number. I did the entire program there is no compilation error but in the output it prints to all pairs except the duplicate pair(i want it to print only the pair whose sum= a prime number) can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prime {
    public static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // a list of integers that was accepted, can be acced in the order they were added
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int inputs = 4; 
        input(inputs);
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs; i++){ 
            for(int j = 0+i; j < inputs; j++){
                if(i != j) 
                    System.out.println(numbers.get(i)+ " + " + numbers.get(j) + " = "+ isPrime(numbers.get(i) + numbers.get(j)));                  
            }
        }   }   

    public static int isPrime (int sumPair)
    {
        boolean primeVal =true ;
        if(sumPair < 2)
            primeVal= false;            
        else if(sumPair ==2)
            primeVal=true;         
        else if (sumPair % 2 == 0)
            primeVal = false;
        else
        {
            int stop = (int)Math.sqrt(sumPair);
            for (int d = 3; d <= stop && primeVal; d = d + 2)
            {
                if (sumPair % d == 0)
                    primeVal = false;
            }
        }
        return(sumPair);
    }

    public static void input(int inputNumbers) 
    {
        while(numbers.size() < inputNumbers){ // while there is more inputs needed
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
            int num = input.nextInt();
            if(num > 0) // if the input is valid
                numbers.add(num);
            else // if the input is not valid
                while (num <= 0) { // while the input is not valid
                    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
                    num = input.nextInt(); // get the next int if it wasn't valid
                    if(num > 0) { // if the input gets valid
                        numbers.add(num);
                    }
                }
            System.out.println("Thank you.");
        }
    }

    public static int sumPair(int num1, int num2)
    {    
        return num1 + num2;
    }

}
```

Comment: How about you debug it and find out which one of your methods is not working correctly? You could leave out `sumPair(int,int)`, since it isn't even being called.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Shouldn't something called `isPrime` return a *boolean* value, not an *integer* value?  (Come to think of it, `isPrime` doesn't even *do anything*.  It just returns whatever value you give it.)  Method names should imply what the method does.  Otherwise you're just confusing yourself.  In your output, where do you try to filter out prime numbers?  Your nested loops in `main()` print all non-duplicate pairs.  There's no attempt to print anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You go to a lot of trouble to compute a boolean `primeVal` which tells whether the input be `true` or `false`, but you never actually return this value.  Try this instead:

```
public static boolean isPrime (int sumPair) {
    boolean primeVal = true;
    if (sumPair < 2 || sumPair % 2 == 0) {
        primeVal = false;            
    }      
    else {
        int stop = (int)Math.sqrt(sumPair);
        for (int d=3; d <= stop; d += 2) {
            if (sumPair % d == 0) {
                primeVal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return primeVal;
}
```

Use this `main()` method:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int inputs = 4; 
    input(inputs);
    for (int i=0; i < inputs-1; i++) { 
        for (int j=i+1; j < inputs; j++) {
            boolean prime = isPrime(numbers.get(i) + numbers.get(j));
            if (prime) {
                System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " + " + numbers.get(j));
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You return a boolean in a function that returns an int. Also, you failed to notice the simple logic error in the main function.

Comment: @Lunar The original `isPrime()` method _always_ returns the input.  This seems to me to be the biggest problem.

Comment: So I returned the Boolean function but in my output in started to show up true and false instead of a number @lunar

Comment: @karthika I don't see any other obvious problems with your code.  What other problems are you having?

Comment: It prints out true and false instead of the sum number .. if I put in primeVal in there @tim

Comment: @karthika I gave you an implementation for your `main()` method which should work.  Just check each pair whether it be prime or not, and print out that pair only in the former case.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition to determine if you print the current pair or not is `if(i != j)`, so it will only print if i is different from j (duplicate).

You made a nice isPrime function, you should call it.

You made your isPrime function return an int, and I'm pretty sure it should return a boolean instead. Also, it returns the argument you gave it, so it does virtually nothing except spend time in a potentially expensive operation. Perhaps should it return primeVal instead.

Your code should look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputs; i++){ 
  for(int j = 0+i; j < inputs; j++){
    ni = numbers.get(i);
    nj = numbers.get(j);
    if(isPrime(ni+nj)){
      System.out.println(ni + " + " + nj + " = "+  (ni + nj));                  
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is get the numbers for indexes i and j and store them in ni and nj respectively. Then, it checks it their sum is prime. If it is, then it prints the sum.

Comment: So when I return primeVal it prints out true and false instead of the sum(number)

Comment: You shouldn't print the result of this function. You should print if the result of this function is true. See the update I made to my post.